# App Store Link broken

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

My app is now launched but when I text or tweet out the link sometimes it directs to the app in the App Store and sometimes it goes to a site that just shows itunes.apple.com and it just looks like this image. Any reason why this is happening? Thanks! [image]

Comment: The problem might be with the link.  You should post it.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.